# Apply a function to a column in pandas giving issues

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am trying to convert string to int for a column in my dataframe.

I have amount column contains values like this:

```
123,123
(343,344)
```

I am converting this:

```
123123
343344
```

For that my code I wrote:

```
def strToInt(str2):
    '''print(type(str2))'''
    if type(str2) == str:
        temp = str2.replace("(", "").replace(")","").replace(",","")
        '''print("GOT :" + str2 + "     RETURN :" + str(int(temp)))'''
        if checkInt(temp):
              return int(temp)
    return None

def checkInt(s):
    if s[0] in ('-', '+'):
        return s[1:].isdigit()
    return s.isdigit()



print(df['amount'])

df['amount'] = df[['amount']].apply(lambda a: strToInt(a))
print(df['amount'])
print(df.columns)

print(df['amount'])
```

But I am getting all null values:
I check the function strToInt individually, it giving correct output.

But after apply I am getting all NaN values.

Before:

```
0            45,105 
1            24,250 
2          8,35,440 
3          3,00,900 
4          1,69,920
```

After:

```
0         NaN
1         NaN
2         NaN
3         NaN
4         NaN
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: What about doing instead: `df['col'].str.replace(r'\D', '', regex=True).astype(int)`?

Comment: @mozway Looks like he wants to handle negative values too.

Comment: @Learningisamess should be easy to handle: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71381516/16343464), one would need more examples of potential inputs to be exhaustive

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use a regex to make things more efficient:

````
df = pd.DataFrame({'amount': ['123,456', '(123,456)', '-123,465', '(-123,456)']})

df = df['amount'].str.replace(r'[^-\d]', '', regex=True).astype(int)
```
output:
```
0    123456
1    123456
2   -123465
3   -123456
Name: amount, dtype: int64
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Pass function to column `df['amount']`, not one column `DataFrame` - `df[['amount']]`:

```
df['amount'] = df['amount'].apply(strToInt)

print (df)
   amount
0   45105
1   24250
2  835440
3  300900
4  169920
```

Solution from comments wotking with negative sign:

```
a = np.where(df['amount'].str.startswith('-'), -1, 1)
df['amount'] = df['amount'].str.replace(r'\D', '', regex=True).astype(int).mul(a)
```